# Aligning pickerviews with Swift correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints, pickerview

How can I align these pickerviews to appear exactly how they are on my storyboard?
I have tried to constrain each of them to 0 on their left and right, but sometimes they disappear when I try to have their bottom or top constraint to a lower number, sometimes I even try to set them to negative.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrLTs.png]

Comment: wow... you may need _one_ picker-view with _multiple_ components maybe...?

Comment: that sounds like a good idea, just don't have a good understanding how to create that

Comment: like any other picker-view, but with _more than one_ components... here is the [data-source delegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdatasource) reference from Apple, that may give ideas to you.